# clean and reuse open port. winsock c++

Tags: c++, sockets, port

I am working on a client-server application where I have two different ports, one (principal) for us send and receive messages or any other order, and another one to send and receive screenshots of the server to the client. From client to server notice to start us send'll catch and showing in a new window ... works fine but if I close the window and open it again then and I can not connect to that port (bind fails me).

MY question is how do I clean or completely release the port I use for screenshots without affecting the main port, that is, when you close the window to release the port  as if I had never used and advise the client to do the same.

Here I leave the code:

Server:

```
int serviceCapture(int port)
{
    int error;
    WSAData wsaDataER;

    error = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaDataER);

    if (error == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        return 1;
    }

   // ShowMessage ("Server: WinSocket Started Correctly!\n");
    sock_ER = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sock_ER == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        return 2;
    }

    struct sockaddr_in escritorioRem; // New! Our network socket structure
    escritorioRem.sin_family = AF_INET; // Always have ti as this for internet
    escritorioRem.sin_port = htons(puerto); // Dont forget the byte ordering
    escritorioRem.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;internet
  if(!enviandoCapturas){
    error = bind(sock_ER, (sockaddr*)&escritorioRem, sizeof(escritorioRem)); // Attempt to bind the socket

    if (error == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {   
        return 3 ;
    }
  }

    error = listen(sock_ER, 1); // Listen for connections

    if (error == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {

        return 4;
    }
    // }
    //ShowMessage ( "Server: Waiting for a client to connect ...\n"); // Just to keep us up to date - ish
      int len= sizeof (struct sockaddr);
      sock_ER=accept(sock_ER,(sockaddr*)&escritorioRem, &len);
     //
    //do{
       if( sock_ER<0){

          return 5;
       }

    sendingCaps=true;

    startSendCaps();

    return 0;
}
```

Client:

```
    int client(string serv, int puerto)
{


    int error;
    WSAData wsaData;

    error = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);

    if (error == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {

        return 1;
    }

   // ShowMessage( "Client: WinSocket Loaded.\n");


    if (sock == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {

        return 2;
    }

   // ShowMessage( "Client: Socket Opened Successfully!\n");


    const char *server_name = serv.c_str(); // The server name we will connect to


    struct hostent *host_entry; // Translates into something the computer can understand


    host_entry = gethostbyname(server_name); // Gather out information

    if (host_entry == NULL)
    {

        return 3;
    }


    struct sockaddr_in server;

    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons((unsigned short) puerto);
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = *(unsigned long*) host_entry->h_addr;


  if(connect(ventanaCliente->sock, (sockaddr*)&server, sizeof(struct sockaddr))<0){

      return 4;
  }
   receivingCaps=true;
   strartReceiveCaps();
    return 0;
}
```